# Why does unstaking require a staking public key?

Tags: nearprotocol

In order to unstake itself, an account needs to issue a staking transaction with `amount=0` but the format of the staking action requires to also specify a staking public key. Is this public key used for anything during unstaking or is it redundant information which is ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is redundant information. It is done this way so that we don't have to introduce another type of transaction.

Comment: Got it, submitted an issue: https://github.com/nearprotocol/nearcore/issues/1713